# Prevent multiple logins of account at a time in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, authorization

How to allow users to log in to your account from only one device at a time in ASP.NET MVC and also handle unexpected shutdowns of the machine or browser. If the user attempts to log in to the account from another browser or machine, they should need to log in again.

As far as this problem is concerned, I have tried multiple ways to solve it and come up with many solutions:

1. Create a table in your database to store user session information. This table should have columns like `UserId`, `SessionId`, and `IsActive`. When a user logs in, generate a unique session identifier (e.g., a GUID) and store it in the session state (`Session["SessionId"]`). Insert a record into the session table with the user's ID, the generated session identifier, and `IsActive` set to true. Add a check during the login process to see if the user already has an active session. If an active session exists, you can choose to prevent the user from logging in from the new device/browser. This option resolves the issue of logging in to your account from only one device at a time.
2. If a user tries to open our account from any other device when the account is already logged in, I give them an option to terminate the existing session. If the user decides to terminate the existing session, set `IsActive` to false for the previous session record in the database and update the session identifier. However, in this scenario, I personally feel a security threat if any other person involved in malware or unauthorized activities tries to open the account. It should allow the user to log in with the credentials.
3. Implement a session expiration mechanism in the application to handle scenarios where the user's browser or machine unexpectedly shuts down. However, in this case, I have set the minimum session timeout time to 20 minutes, which I don't want to decrease. So, if a user's machine or browser unexpectedly shuts down within 2 minutes, the user would have to wait till 20 minutes to log in until the session expires.
4. The last thing I implemented is a web service that runs 24/7 hours on the server and monitors the user's last activity after every 2 minutes. If no activity is detected from the login account for the last 2 minutes, it automatically logs out the account. This helps me achieve my goal, but I have millions of users in my application, so after every 2 minutes, the server sends requests to all login users and checks their activity, which increases the server load.

I need help from you guys to come up with the best possible solution. I've tried all my knowledge in this, but I have not yet come up with the best possible solution.

Comment: Regarding 4, you should never poll the database.  Set a timestamp in the database (or probably a cache would be better) of when the last activity occurred, and if another activity occurs between the stored activity plus an offset, then the user should be logged out.

Comment: Regarding 1. Don't store an 'IsActive' flag, store the time that that session was started, and update it every time the user does something.  Again, a cache is your friend here because you aren't constantly writing to a database (which might be expensive in time and or money).

Comment: You have no idea if a user is on your site, and shuts their lid on the laptop, or now used a bookmark to go shopping on amazon. Web systems are state-less, and you really don't know when they left your site. If you REALLY want to do this, then adopt SignalR or a websocket system and with that live working connection to the server you can "talk" to the server every 5 seconds or whatever you want time wise resolving.  You often can't even use session timeout, and even a user returning does not always trigger session start. A real time socket connection is quite much the best solution here.

Comment: Don't know about the detecting crashes part, I think that'd be really difficult to implement if you really want to do it. If we can ignore that one, what about JWT in session cookie? Store create time and identity information in the jwt, then store the jwt in the DB and client cookie. When user logs out (maybe through a button), erase the DB column and the cookie; if user closes the browser, the cookie would be cleared and can't be validated with DB jwt. You'd need to be careful about XSRF issues though.

Comment: Btw, seems more like a opinion-based question?

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal 
I've tried using SignalR and WebSocket to resolve this problem, which probably helps me to achieve the desired end result. However, issues occur when I have a million active users at the same time. Consequently, I need to monitor and send requests from SignalR or WebSocket, which is costly in terms of implementation for the complex system. Do you have any other ideas that could be helpful?

Comment: @XiangWeiHuang
I've tried the JWT token as well but the unexpected shutdown part didn't work with it. Do you have any other ideas that could be helpful?

Comment: Like what Albert said, even SignalR/websocket approach still can't distinguish if user closed their browser gracefully or crashed. All you'll know is that connection is closed or not. If it's me, I'd re-confirm the actual requirement, is the unexpected shutdown handling really necessary? ~20 minutes cooldown after a crash sounds odd to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding more features to improve and trust the user login attempt

1. Implement MFA (Multi factor auth, like RSA Token, Microsoft
   Authenticator, OTP etc)
2. Register Device in db to easily switch session between machines for trusted user and his devices.
3. force terminate prev session to keep it simple and that is still valid since the initiated session from that device is abandoned.

Comment: Yes, this was the last option that I considered implementing in this type of system. **Thanks for your suggestion**